# How to unbind i2c bus 0 from the i2c driver?

Tags: raspbian, i2c

It seems a I2C component (Gyroscope) I am using  with my Raspberry Pi B+ makes my Pi Camera hangs after a while.

I read I must unbind the i2c bus 0 from the Linux (Raspbian) from the i2c driver. I tried the following command but it didn't work:

sudo -s
echo bcm2708_i2c.0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/bcm2708_i2c/unbind

bash: echo: write error: No such device
Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Doesn't B+ make use of i2c bus 1 ?

Comment: Also, you have an error in your command i think. It should be, sudo sh -c "echo bcm2708_i2c.0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/bcm2708_i2c/unbind" if you're running it from pi user.

Answer (score 1):

Using sudo this way has a caveat:

```
sudo -s echo bcm2708_i2c.0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/bcm2708_i2c/unbind
                          ^^^
```

The `>` redirects the output of the command which is run `sudo`, but the redirection itself is done as the regular user.  In this case, that won't fly. Instead, `su root`, do whatever, and then `exit` to return to your regular user.

I doubt this will fix your [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) though.